# Comandos batch Move e Del não estão funcionando

Tags: windows, script, batch, cmd

```
@echo OFF

mkdir saida

sort %1 > cadperfiSorted 2>> saida\error.txt

start MAKEOPEACER5.jar cadperfiSorted

del cadperfiSorted
//OPEACER5 é um arquivo gerado pelo .jar
move OPEACER5 saida
```

Esse é o script que estou tentando executar.
Tudo parece funcionar bem o problema é que a função `del` e a função `move` simplesmente não funciona.

Comment: É possível que o comando que executa o .jar (java?) ainda não tenha terminado. Com isso, o `del` está tentando apagar um arquivo em uso (que não conseguirá), e o `move` está tentando mover um arquivo que ainda não existe. Tente usar o `start /wait MAKEOPEACER5...`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 1):

O comando `start` do batch não espera que o comando *started* termine. O que deve estar acontecendo é que o comando `MAKEOPEACER5.jar cadperfiSorted` ainda não terminou, e com isso:

- o `del` falha, já que está tentando acessar um arquivo em uso
- o `move` falha, já que está tentando mover um arquivo que (ainda) não existe

Tente usar a opção `/wait` para que o comando só continue quando a operação terminar:

```
start /wait MAKEOPEACER5.jar cadperfiSorted
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.Funcionou perfeitamente aqui.